# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting properly from external SSD

Tags: boot, 16.04, ssd

I have a Lenovo S340 and I've just gone through and installed Ubuntu 16.04 w/ a EFI partition onto an external SSD via the Ubuntu installer.

The SSD properly shows up in the boot menu + BIOS monitor, but when the SSD is selected it directly goes to windows instead of booting Ubuntu off of the SSD.

I've tried `boot-repair` via the live usb I installed the Ubuntu from, and disabling secure boot to no avail.

Why might this be happening, and what possible fixes might there be?

Comment: UEFI only boots external USB devices from /EFI/Boot. Newer versions of Grub now creates that file if you install grub to the external device (not sure about 16.04's version). But the Ubiquity installer always defaults to install grub to first internal drive, usually sda or first NVMe drive. Do you have boot files /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu on external drive, both required? Boot-Repair's advanced options should let you install grub to external. Or copy /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu from internal drive's ESP to external drive's ESP.

Comment: Did you see the post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144049/ubuntu-on-lenovo-ideapad-s340-intel-i3-8-gig? I haven't installed Linux on my S340 yet. But JBryan's description of BIOS issues matches mine so far. So I will be checking his advise. Others have also referenced need to use AHCI mode. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also have same issue while making duel boot. there is one option that you can make install is to change your SATA configuration mode my laptop default is SATA config -> intel but that one not compatible with installing ubuntu. so i changed to AHCI mode, so i can install ubuntu it will detect your disk. but only the drawback for this method is that everytime you need to switch back to intel mode if you want to use windows.

FOR CHANGING THE MODE you goto boot->SATA configuration-> AHCI/Intel

note: disable secure boot and fast boot